# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: python, binary, byte, ascii

i was trying to make **ascii** from binary. but i got error
**'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 1: invalid start byte**

here's my code, please help me

```
def stringmodulasi(f):
    f = "11110000111110101111001100000110000001110000001000001011111111101111111111111010000011001111100111110111111100101111010011111110"
    binary = int(f)
    print(binary)
    ascii_text = binary.to_bytes((binary.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode() //result = ����
    return ascii_text
```

the result i want like [this website converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-ascii.html)

Comment: no because all i want to make ascii @sahasrara62

Comment: decode.encode.decode ?

Comment: still got error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 2: invalid continuation byte @sahasrara62

Comment: try use `.decode('ascii',errors='replace')` this will give you a proper stirng, allso change `binary = int(f, 2)`

Comment: Where does the `f` bitstring come from? It has 128 bits, so it's an 8 bit format (proper ASCII is 7 bit), but it's not readable English text in the usual 8 bit ASCII extensions (Latin1 or cp1252), and it's not valid UTF-8.

Comment: it's not error again, thank you for your help @sahasrara62

Comment: hello, if i want to make the result ascii to binary 1 0, how to do it? @sahasrara62

Comment: You can ask this question again in stack overflow, sure u will get help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74618585/how-to-convert-metadata-to-binary-in-python is my new post for the problem @sahasrara62

Comment: U need to do reverse of the current process